# How to get the amount of physical memory cached and free in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, performancecounter, taskmanager

I'm trying to mimic Windows 7 task manager (Performance tab only) in C#, and while I've managed to get most values, I'm unable to get the cached and free byte values for physical memory. I know by definition they mean:

> - Cached refers to the amount of physical memory used recently for system resources.
> - Free is the amount of memory that is currently unused or doesn't contain useful information (unlike cached files, which do contain useful information).

But none of my approaches resulted in the exact value shown in task manager. e.g:

**Cached:**

```
PerformanceCounter PC4 = new PerformanceCounter();
PC4.CategoryName = "Memory";
PC4.CounterName = "Cache Bytes";
PC4.InstanceName = "";
Console.WriteLine((Int32)(PC4.NextValue() / (1024 * 1024)));
```

**Free:**

```
ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
object ob = 0;
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
  ob = result["FreePhysicalMemory"];
}//returns physical memory's <i>Available</i> byte, NOT <i>Free</i>
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You are missing several more counters that go in the "Cached" bracket.  Like "Standby Cache Reserve Bytes".  Ask at superuser.com how these add up.

Comment: Any idea on how to retrieve those values from C# point of view?

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the System.Diagnostics.Process class.
I think Process.PagedMemorySize is what you are interested in.
The following code sample will spit out a list of running processes and their mem usage:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process p in processlist){
    Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1} MEM:{2}”, p.ProcessName, p.Id, theprocess.PagedMemorySize);
}
```

If PagedMemorySize is not the one try maybe VirtualMemorySize64

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is a lot of memory related properties in Process and I am not familiar with all of them so you should check them out

Comment: I tried summing up the amount of WorkingSet64, ,NonpagedSystemMemorySize64, VirtualMemorySize64, PagedMemorySize64 and PrivateMemorySize64 for every process (the last two actually return the same number). None of them correspond to Cached or Free ram.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add references to Microsoft.VisualBasic to use the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

public class MemStat
{
    public ulong Available { get; set; }

    public ulong Total { get; set; }

    public ulong PhysicalMemoryInUse { get; set; }

    public ulong Free { get; set; }

    public ulong Cached { get; set; }

    public MemStat()
    {
        ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);

        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        var Available = new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory;

        this.Available = Available;

        var Total = new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;

        this.Total = Total;

        var PhysicalMemoryInUse = Total - Available;

        this.PhysicalMemoryInUse = PhysicalMemoryInUse;

        Object Free = new object();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Free = result["FreePhysicalMemory"];

            this.Free = ulong.Parse(Free.ToString());

        }

        var Cached = Total - PhysicalMemoryInUse - ulong.Parse(Free.ToString());

        this.Cached = Cached;

    }
```

Then use it like so:

```
        ulong TotalMemory = new MemStat().Total;
        ulong FreeMemory = new MemStat().Free;

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("    **** MY WINDOWS PROGRAM ****     ");
        Console.WriteLine("" + (TotalMemory/1024) + "K RAM SYSTEM " + FreeMemory + " BYTES FREE");
```